# filter that prints a value and then forwards the entire json document to the next filter, like tee

Tags: jq, tee

Is it possible to print parts of the document in a filter and then move on to select further down and print more later?

Here is pseudo code for what I want.

```
{
    "version":"1",
    "some":{
        "more":{
            "depth":"here"
        }
    }
}

select(.some.more.depth=="here") | tee .version | .some.more.depth
```

This would output

```
"1"
"here"
```

I know, that in this case, it would work with `.version, .some.more.depth` but in a more complex case it's more about working down the document while printing parts along the way.

https://jqplay.org/s/n7WjphEVf7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not just in this case, in any case. That's what the comma operator does, and what it's for. It runs two expressions in the same context and produces all of the outputs of both. Remember that you can always use parentheses, so it's legit to do things like

```
.a.b.c | (.d, .e.f | (.g, .h))
```

to produce `.a.b.c.d`, `.a.b.c.e.f.g`, and `.a.b.c.e.f.h`

Comment: Or even just put the full paths for all values you want printed.

Comment: @JeffMercado of course, but when there are other things in there than just dot operators, you really do want to avoid the repetition.

Comment: This is why jq has such great potential for parallel processing!  Any takers?